# Wordpress and WPforms survey - How to make an unregistered user compile the form only once (using the cookie session)

Tags: wordpress, session, cookies

I've a problem with WPForm survey.

In my website, I need to create 4 different surveys in 4 different pages.

Ex. mysite.com/demo-survey1 / mysite.com/demo-survey2 / mysite.com/demo-survey3 / mysite.com/demo-survey4

The question is: I need to allow anonymous (NOT wp registered, only visitors) users to compile and send the survey form but at the same time I must prevent them from voting more than **once**. It is possible maybe with a cookie session rule snippet?

How can I achieve that with custom code? Thank you in advance